# Blackberry phonegap access Documents

Tags: cordova, blackberry

Is it possible for a Blackberry Phonegap app to read and write to the Documents directory? The one you see with BlackBerry Link.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to access the shared directory using cordova.file.sharedDirectory with the [File plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file).  You can read and write the documents folder located there.

The shared folder is shared between applications.  For example the shared/downloads folder will contain downloads from the web browser.

Please see the [webworks documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/cordova_file_file.md.html), and the [BB10 file system documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/file_system.html) for more information.

EDIT: 
Perhaps you are missing permissions.  Try adding the following to your config.xml:

```
<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>
```

Comment: I have tried that plugin but I simple get error code 1, which is file not found.


    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.sharedDirectory, function (entry) {
      console.log(entry);
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

Comment: You might be missing permissions, give the edit up top a shot.

Comment: I do have that, and I get a notification to ask permission for that when installing the app

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  What happens when you use `/accounts/1000/shared` in place of  `cordova.file.sharedDirectory`?

Comment: Ok so the problem was answered here:

https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Can-t-read-shared-folders-and-files-always-returns-error/td-p/2882504

I guess the cordova file plugin was overriding window.requestFileSystem so I had to prefix it with webkit to ensure I use to right one.

Comment: Again, weird.  Strange that resolveLocalFileSystemURL didn't work. If you look at the plugin code, the `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` function ends up invoking `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`.